# Multiple selenium request in same driver - no timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have the following problem. I'm fetching several pages with the same driver, because of the extensive login procedure.
The first fetch goes okay and the second fetch does not timeout and does nothing. The script 'hangs'.

The driver is Firefox and the webpage is a sharepoint server. And I don't have access to the api.

Profile setup:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
profile.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 10)
```

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

list_old = []
list_old.append('https://shareointsite1.com')
list_old.append('https://shareointsite1.com/list1')
list_old.append('https://shareointsite1.com/list2')

for a in list_old:
    driver.get(a)

    timeout = 5
    print("website: wait for page load")
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ms-webpart-zone'))

        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
```

I tried refreshing the page, and navigating to other pages but no luck. The second attempt always 'hangs' the script.

Comment: can you provide the output. At which line does it hang ?

Comment: The output is: website: wait for page load
It's waiting for the element to load. But its already there and the timeout of 5 seconds never gets fired (TimeoutException).